# Where can I find an image of the Thales FMS220 RMS page?

Tags: fms

I'm looking for photo/color image showing Thales FMS220 RMS (Radio Management System) page. Also COMMUNICATION and XPDR pages are highly welcome.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Thales directly?

Comment: @FreeMan - Yeah, mail was send, still waiting for any answer. But probably, if i'm not an air company, it is hopeless.

Comment: @mins - There is one user manual on different servers, but not including these pages. Probably ask reali life pilot to take shots is only option.

Comment: @Robert: That seems a good question, at least to me and another user ;-)

Answer (score -2):

The answer is on the official website, here is a direct link:

https://fr.scribd.com/doc/204747124/Fms-User-Guide

You need to go to the website yourself because the document content is not to be disclosed without official approval.